# How to display errors when error occurs using bootstrap in php

Tags: php, html, css

I am building a contact form with php and bootstrap and I want to show bootstrap alerts when an error occurs. So my problem now is that I have already got the code to work and it checks the error but the error alert dialog is displayed before the error occurs

I have tried to move the error dialog below the HTML, but I am still getting the same error

```
$email = $name = $subject = $message = '';

$errors = ['email' => '', 'name' => '', 'subject' => '', 'message' => ''];

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    // check email
    if (empty($_POST['email'])) {
        $errors['email'] = "An email is required !";
    } else {
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $errors['email'] = "Enter a validemail address !";
        }
    } 


<div class="form-group">

    <label for="email" class="bmd-label-floating">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="<?php htmlspecialchars($email)?>">
    <div class="mt-2 alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
        <?php echo $errors['email'] ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

The expected behavior should be to show the error in the error dialog when the an error occurs, not the error dialog occur before the error occurs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to wrap the modal with an `if` to check that there is actually an error.

```
<?php if($errors['email']): ?>
<div class="mt-2 alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
    <?php echo $errors['email'] ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a check before displaying the error. Like Below

```
<?php
if(isset($errors['email']) && $errors['email']!=''){ 
?>
<div class="mt-2 alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
        <?php echo $errors['email']; ?>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: @Gaurav There's no need for `isset`, since it's surely set.